# My input and if is not working... How do I fix my code? Python 2.7.16

Tags: python-2.7

My if statement is not working:

```
choice = float(input("Enter 1 to enter sec. Enter 2 to enter mins")):
#My problem:
if 'choice' == 1
    a = float(input("Enter secs"))
```

etc...

BTW, I was making a timer, but I need to know... It told me invalid syntax...

Comment: I edited it so it works now

Comment: Remember... it's 2.7.16.

Comment: I hope it works for you :)

Comment: the literal string `'choice'` will never ever equal the integer `1`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out a loooong time ago ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed code (with my comments):

```
choice = int(raw_input("Enter 1 to enter sec. Enter 2 to enter mins")) # no need to use float here, also in python2 please use raw_input
if choice == 1:  # you tried to compare `choice` string with 1 (always False), compare choice variable value with 1 instead. Also note, that you missed : after if
    a = float(input("Enter secs"))
```

Comment: Figure you need to add the ':' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
choice + int(input("Bla bla bla")):
```

I forgot the **':'**